# how to suppress simplification of formulas to True or False?

Tags: z3, z3py

is it possible to disable automatic simplifications of boolean expressions in Z3?

For example, the expression 2 > 1 becomes True automatically while I would like it to stay 2 > 1:

```
>>> t = 2 > 1
>>> t
True
```

I found several options by calling help_simplify() in Z3Py. However, none of them seems to relate to my problem.

In another tutorial (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.225.8231) an option "CONTEXT SIMPLIFIER" was mentioned: "This setting can be used to simplify sub-formulas to true or false." However, I could not find this option in Z3Py.

Background: I would like to be able to use expressions like And(2>1, 1!=2) where 2>1 and 1!=2 are automatically generated earlier and sometimes contain no variables (constants). Z3Py simplifies this to And(True, False) which is not accepted, because  "At least one of the arguments must be a Z3 expression or probe". Therefore, I would like to suppress the simplification. Or is there a way to make And(True, False) an accepted expression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, I just noticed that this simplification is already done by the python interactive shell: it evaluates the simple comparison 2 > 1 before Z3Py actually could even do it. However, my question remains: how to suppress this and hand Z3Py the term "2 > 1" and/or how to allow And(True,False) expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is because simple expressions like 2>1 are simplified to True/False by Python. Most operators (like Implies, Xor, ...) were fine with this, but the And and Or operators were not. They had a different implementation because they can be used for probes as well as expressions. I have now added a little bit more code to make them behave like the other Boolean operators (for fix see [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/756645326bb2c0578b340e05e03c8276cacd1dd9)). I hope this fixes this problem while not introducing any new problems with probes. I'd be grateful if other could test this some more.

Comment: I circumvented the problem by using IntVal(..) and BoolVal(..) instead of integer literals and boolean constants: IntVal(2) > IntVal(1) is not simplified by the python interactive shell, therefore And(BoolVal(True), IntVal(2) > IntVal(1)) is accepted as well